# is there a way to select just the outer surface but not the inner?

Tags: modeling, mesh, objects, edit-mode, geometry

I've got some faces inside an object, but i want to delete them.
Is there a way to select all the outer surface without inner ?
[image]

[image]

Comment: i'd say you should have that hair mesh in a separate object, select some geometry and expand it with Ctrl + (PLUSKEY) until it encompasses all the "outside geometry" then hit Ctrl + I to invert your selection and delete the selection you are left with

Answer (score 3):

You probably have got the ***nonmanifold elements*** there. Select the whole mesh in *Edit Mode* (<kbd>A</kbd>), go to *Select*-->*NonMannifold*, then delete the edges.
[image]

You may also use a ***MeshLint*** add on to do it. Activate it in *User Preferences* (<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>U</kbd>). Go to the *MeshLint* panel of the *Data* header, check the *NonManifold Elements* checkbox and click *Select Lint* button.
[image]
[image]